# two tables one is of access database and other is of oracle database, I am getting an error saying that ‘SQL odbc error’ what should I do?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using two tables one is of access database and other is of oracle database, I am getting an error saying that ‘SQL odbc error’ what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do.

1. Make a test report.
2. Link it to **one** of the 2 databases.
3. Drag some fields from your source into the report.
4. Can you preview this test report? If not, that datasource may be the problem.
5. Do the same thing with the other datasource.
6. If both reports work fine, make a new test report that joins the 2 datasources. If this doesn't work, then your 2 data sources may not be matching up in some way.

Answer (score 0):

"SQL odbc error" always refers to some kind of connection error via an ODBC connection.  (These connections can be managed via the Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources)

Follow PowerUsers steps above, but test the Access connection first, since it is the one most likely to be connected via ODBC. Oracle may be ODBC, or it may be a direct TNS connection, so I would suspect the Access DB first.

Once you identifiy which one (or both) of your connections is a problem, then you need to figure out what it is.  The likely culprits are:

1. The name or IP of your ODBC connection is wrong
2. The user name in the connection is wrong
3. The password in the connection is wrong
4. They are all correct, but the user doesn't have permissions to view the tables the report was built with.